# Creating two rows for the same reference depending on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to pull data from database in the following format:

```
No | Ref |  Net  |  Vat  | VatCode
--------------------------------
1  |  1  |  250  |  NULL |   T0
2  |  2  | 83.61 |  NULL |   T0
3  |  2  |  NULL | 16.72 |   T1
4  |  3  |  300  |  NULL |   T0
```

So if VatCode equals to T0 then it shows ONE row:

- Net value, NULL for Vat and T0 for VatCode;

But if VatCode equals to T1 then we need to create two rows for the same Ref:

- first row should contain Net value, NULL for Vat and T0 for VatCode;
- second row should contain NULL for Net, Vat value and T1 for VatCode

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using `union all`:

```
select No, Ref, Net, NULL as Vat, 'T0' as VatCode
from t
where VatCode in ('T0', 'T1')
union all
select No, Ref, NULL as Net, Vat, VatCode
from t
where VatCode = 'T1';
```

EDIT:

If `No` is not part of the original data:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as No, Ref, Net, Vat, VatCode
from (select Ref, Net, NULL as Vat, 'T0' as VatCode
      from t
      where VatCode in ('T0', 'T1')
      union all
      select Ref, NULL as Net, Vat, VatCode
      from t
      where VatCode = 'T1'
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of crystal ball?

Comment: hmmm.. the OP is asking for a unique sequential `No`, probably not part of `t`...

Comment: @Dario . . . Good observation.

Comment: How do you order result by something by the way?

Comment: @DenissMuntjans . .  Use `order by`.